# Starting playframework netty in prodmode with ssl

Tags: ssl, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm trying to start a Play appication in Prodmode with a SSL-certificate. I created a jks file with java keytool and it worked without problems.
Now I want to start the application on my Server with the following command

```
./bin/myApplication -Dhttps.keyStore=/var/www/vhosts/myApplication.de/ssl/ssl.jks -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=123456 -Dhttps.port=443 -Dhttp.port=disabled -Dhttps.keyStoreAlgoritm=jks
```

The Problem is is the following error:

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
        [error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: ﾼMￚﾚ▒Eￆ￐￹/L￀ﾛﾁKﾕ￁0V&M
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
            at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.7.1.Final.jar:na]
```

I alredy tried to start the application local with play generated certificate and it worked fine. The application is running also in Prodmode without SSL... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake, here my complete way to get (and start) the play application in prod mode:

- Order a ssl certificate, for that I created a csr-file with that command

> openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myserver.key -out
>   server.csr

- Important (I think this was my mistake), the server software used to generate the CSR is tomcat, not java webserver
- When I got my crt-file by the ssl provider I made a p12-file

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey myserver.key -out abc.p12

- Then I created a jks-file

> keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
>   -destkeystore abc.jks -deststoretype jks

- Now it's possible to start the server

> http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ConfiguringHttps

Answer (score 0):

Try the Activator TLS example: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-play-tls-example